# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, Arrays, and Counting Occurrences of Integers

Tags: java, arrays

I've been on this assignment for two days now and I'm having such a difficult time!
My assignment asks me to create a program that:

- asks how many times the user would like to perform the run (e.g. 3
  flips of 20) (the output should have a comparison between each trial)
- asks the user how many times he would like his coin to flip (he can
  flip up to 1000 times)
- randomly generates a number between 1 and ten,
  store all the numbers in an array

It must also show how many times each number out of 10 showed up, what number showed up the most, and if even numbers are heads, and odd numbers are tails, what side of the coin came up the most. 
Please help me, I've tried writing the code but I'm having such a hard time and I'm really stressed on time!

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ColCoin
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //set variables
    String timesString;
    String run;
    int times;
    int runNum;
    int i = 0;
    int x;

    //input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //random object
    Random r = new Random();

    System.out.print("How many times would you like to perform a run through the flips? ");
    run = br.readLine();
    runNum = Integer.parseInt(run);

    do
    {
        //ask how many times the coin will flip
        System.out.print("Please input the amount of times you would like to flip the coin (1-1000): ");
        timesString = br.readLine();

        //convert String into an integer
        times = Integer.parseInt(timesString);

        if((times > 1000)||(times < 1))
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR! Must input an integer between 1 and 1000!");
        }
        System.out.println("You chose to flip the coin " + times + " times.");
    } while((times > 1000)||(times < 1));

    for(x=0; x <= runNum; x++)
    {
        //create array
        int flip[] = new int[times];
        int countArray[] = new int[i];

        //create a new variable
        int storeTime;

        for(storeTime = 0; storeTime < flip.length; storeTime++)
        {            
            flip[storeTime] = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
            // the line above stores a random integer between 1 and 10 within the current index
            System.out.println("Flip number " + (storeTime+1) + " = " + flip[storeTime]);
        }


        //display the counts
        for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("The occurences of each of the numbers is: ");
            System.out.println((i+1) + " appears " + countArray[i] + "times.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

It also gave an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error on line 64 and I'm not sure why:

```
System.out.println((i+1) + " appears " + countArray[i] + "times.");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of i when you do int countArray[] = new int[i]? That's how big your array is. What is the value of i when you get the exception?

Comment: Don't declare for loop index values globally.  You've totally confused yourself.  `i` is zero when you allocate the array, then you increment it in the loop.

Comment: Note that unless the assignment definitely specifies it, you don't need the flip array at all, since the only part you're displaying is the counts, and you can fill the counts directly by `int result = r.nextInt(10) + 1; flipCounts[result]++;`.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is here:

```
int countArray[] = new int[i];
```

With this code you create an array with i elements, indexed from 0 to i-1. But in your case int is still 0. so the array has dimension zero (also it seems that you never use that array to input something)

```
System.out.println((i+1) + " appears " + countArray[i] + "times.");
```

Here you ask the array to give you the element i!=0, but obviously you cannot because the array is dimensioned as zero.

Comment: I see that somebody was faster than me :p.

Comment: @Sal I think that it should be set to 10. You need 10 elements, rigth?

Comment: actually, the array is never filled, so, it's always empty and unuseful

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in this part

> int countArray[] = new int[i];

At the time of creation of this array i is Zero thus actually, the array is never filled, so, it's always empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dynamic length in the array, but the loop you created to display the output you are using a fixed length (The line below).

`for(i=0; i < 10; i++)`